# Generating Notification at a time fetched from Database

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am making Reminder application in Android. For that I am storing date and time by getting values from user and storing it to the database in order to generate notification at that particular time.

My Activity is as follows :

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText medWorkTitle;
private EditText medWorkDescription;
private Button mbtnSetTime;
private Button mbtnSetDate;
private Button mbtnSave;
private TextView mtxtDate, mtxtTime;
private RadioGroup mrgWorkValue;
private RadioButton mrbWorkValue;

private Calendar mCalendar;
private int mInt_year, mInt_month, mInt_day;
static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;
//TIME PICKER
private TimePicker timepick1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 111;
private int hour;
private int minute;
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


////Database tasks..
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


public ArrayList<String> strDataList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    init();
    dateTimeUtility();

}

public void init() {
    strDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    medWorkDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWorkDescription);
    medWorkTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWorkTitle);

    mtxtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    mtxtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    mbtnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    mbtnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    mbtnSetDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetDate);
    mbtnSetDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    mbtnSetTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetTime);
    mbtnSetTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    mrgWorkValue = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgWorkValue);


    ///For Database..
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    strDataList = dbHelper.getAllRemiders();


}

public void dateTimeUtility() {
    // FOR DATE-PICKER
    mInt_year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mInt_month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mInt_day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(mInt_year, mInt_month + 1, mInt_day);


    // Current Hour
    hour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    // Current Minute
    minute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // set current time into output textview
    updateTime(hour, minute);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSetDate:
            setDate(view.getRootView());
            break;
        case R.id.btnSetTime:
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSave:
            insertWork();
            initCalender();
            generateNotification();
            break;
    }
}

// /////FOR DATE-PICKER
public void setDate(View view) {
    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, mInt_year,
                    mInt_month, mInt_day);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            // set time picker as current time
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                    false);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        showDate(arg1, arg2 + 1, arg3);
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

    if (day < 10) {

        if (month < 10) {
            mtxtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append("0" + month).append("-").append("0" + day));
        } else {
            mtxtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month).append("-").append("0" + day));
        }

    } else {

        if (month < 10) {
            mtxtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append("0" + month).append("-").append(day));

        } else {
            mtxtDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month).append("-").append(day));
        }
    }

}

////TIMEPICKER
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hour = hourOfDay;
        minute = minutes;

        updateTime(hour, minute);

    }

};

private static String utilTime(int value) {

    if (value < 10)
        return "0" + String.valueOf(value);
    else
        return String.valueOf(value);
}

// Used to convert 24hr format to 12hr format with AM/PM values
private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {

    String timeSet = "";
    if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        timeSet = "PM";
    } else if (hours == 0) {
        hours += 12;
        timeSet = "AM";
    } else if (hours == 12)
        timeSet = "PM";
    else
        timeSet = "AM";


    String minutes = "";
    if (mins < 10)
        minutes = "0" + mins;
    else
        minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

    // Append in a StringBuilder
    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
            .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

    mtxtTime.setText(aTime);
}

public void insertWork() {
    String strWorktitle = medWorkTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    String strWorkDescription = medWorkDescription.getText().toString().trim();
    String strWorkDate = mtxtDate.getText().toString().trim();
    String strWorkTime = mtxtTime.getText().toString().trim();
    String strWorkValue = getWorkValue();

    long id = dbHelper.insertWork(strWorktitle, strWorkDescription, strWorkDate, strWorkTime, strWorkValue, "Incomplete");
    if (id != -1) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Remider Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Reminder can not be Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public String getWorkValue() {
    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
    int selectedId = mrgWorkValue.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    mrbWorkValue = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    return mrbWorkValue.getText().toString().trim();
}

public void generateNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HomeActivity.this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
    Log.d("MCALENDER VALUE : ", "" + mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    Date date2 = new Date(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());

    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Generate Notification Called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"gnTime : "+ date2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void initCalender() {

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date date2 = new Date(time);


    Log.d("+++Current DateTime : ", "" + date2);
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Current DateTime: "+date2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date;
    for (int i = 0; i < strDataList.size(); i++) {

        try {
            System.out.print("+++" + strDataList.get(i).toString());
            date = formatter.parse(strDataList.get(i).toString());
            if (date2 == date) {
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.MONTH, date2.getMonth());
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date2.getDay());
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.YEAR, date2.getYear());
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date2.getHours());
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.MINUTE, date2.getMinutes());
                mCalendar.set(mCalendar.SECOND, date2.getSeconds());
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"Dates Matched "+date2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                generateNotification();
            }
            Log.d("+++DateFromDatabase : ", "" + date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You notice that I am calling functions `initCalender()` and `generateNotification()` on Button's click event.

Problem is : 
It generates notification even if the time not matches as time getting from database.

My Receiver class is as follows :

```
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context,MyRemiderService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }

}
```

My Service class is as follows :

```
 public class MyRemiderService extends Service {
    private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MyRemiderService.this);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                HomeActivity.class);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg,
                "This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha)
                .setContentTitle("ContentTitle").setContentText("this for test massage")
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

        notification = builder.getNotification();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       /* notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!",
                pendingNotificationIntent);*/

        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Please let me to the right way. Thank You.